# Updating The 'Scrollable Text' property To Update Dialog Box Content In Wise Installer

Tags: installation, windows-installer, rtf, wise

While uploading the rtf file through dialog box, the data of the file is trimmed. The full file content is not visible.
The property being used is 'Scrollable Text'  to update the license for the installer.
The license content is 25 pages and only 5 page content is visible in the installer.
Is there a way to update the content for dialog box in wise installer?